# In graphql schema, how can I create a parent/child relationship of same model?

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

I'm needing to create a searchable listing table where some records are of type `ORGANIZATION` or `RESOURCE`. The relationshipis one-to-many. So, an Organization can have many Resources. How can I create this relationship under one model?

Using AWS Amplify GraphQL API...

Like this? `schema.graphql`

```
enum ListingType {
  ORGANIZATION
  RESOURCE
}
type Listing @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  type: ListingType!
  orginzation: Listing
}
```

Yet, in Mutations, I can't reference a parent organization when creating my first Resource:

[image]

Comment: Don't you still need a [@connection](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/graphql?sdk=js#connection) directive on the organization field?

Comment: Hmm, good point. For a One-To-One, @connection would reference the Organization. I'll try it...

Comment: @DanielRearden, that did it. Thank you! Submit your answer and I'll mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include a `@connection` directive for any field that is a relationship, as outlined in the [docs](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/graphql?sdk=js#connection). In this case, something like this should work:

```
type Listing @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  type: ListingType!
  organization: Listing @connection
}
```